# Access docker container's directory from host

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I create a web server container with some default static resources. I'd like to use nginx to proxy the static files, and the Nginx service in the host, so I need to access the static files in container from the host, I try to set the `--volume` when run the container as below:

```
docker run -d 
    --name=some-server 
    -p 8080:8080 
    -v /var/myserver/data:/app/static
    some-server-image
```

and the host directory `/var/myserver/data` is a empty directory, and I found the host's directory covers the container's directory.

Is there any way to access the container's data from host? or any other solutions. Thanks a lot!

PS: I have to manage the static files with the git version control, so some solutions like manage static files use other third party service, not suit for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Take a look here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container). I think the problem is with your notation, you should be specifyng a source **volume**, as opposed to a source **directory**.

Try with:

```
docker run -d 
  --name=some-server 
  -p 8080:8080 
  -v my_nginx_new_volume:/app/static
  some-server-image
```

This should create a new volume, populated with the data from your container's `/app/static` directory.

Even better would be to use `--mount` notation instead of `-v` notation

```
docker run -d \
  --name=nginxtest \
  --mount source=my_nginx_new_volume,destination=/app/static \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  some-server-image
```